# How to show content on click in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a list of categories on the left side. On click of which I need to show a related picture on the right side of the page. JFI I am using the "twenty twenty-three" theme.

I am new to WordPress. I don't know how to show this kind of conditional content.